# Up-to-date breakeven inflation term structure for US and Eurozone

Tags: market-data, inflation, term-structure

I am looking for openly accessible, up-to-date data for the term structure of the breakeven inflation rates in the US and the eurozone. All I can find are static charts that illustrate past news articles.

Does anybody know of a good source? I would really like to avoid having to calculate this myself.

Answer (score 1):

For the US, try https://fred.stlouisfed.org/searchresults?st=breakeven.

Don't know of an "openly accessible" source for EUR.

EDIT: there are of course plenty of sources for EUR that aren't openly accessible, e.g. Bloomberg, Refinitiv (formerly Reuters), various IDBs.